# Grails and Log4J : How to logs in different files with same level?

Tags: grails, log4j

I would like configure Grails log4j to store logs in different files depending of the controller.

So, I have a package.Controller1 and package.Controller2 . 
On controller1, I would like store in logfile1.logs and on controller2 on logfile2.logs in debug mode.

How to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the experiences we've had, you just can't. Maybe we were just unlucky though, so here's to hoping that someone knows the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Create the appenders as file (or rollingFile etc.):

```
appenders {
   file name: "logfile1", file: "/path/to/logfile1.logs"
   file name: "logfile2", file: "/path/to/logfile2.logs"
}
```

and then use the Map syntax to partition the two controllers into separate appenders:

```
debug logfile1: "grails.app.controller.package.Controller1",
      logfile2: "grails.app.controller.package.Controller2"
```

See http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#logging for more details.