# Avoiding Multiple Logging of Same Message Due to Default behaviour in Log4j

Tags: java, grails, logging, log4j

I am working in Grails application and want to log messages in different files. I want to log exceptions, normal and API logs in different files. But according to Log4j general roles, If we set logger level to 'Info' then warn and error messages will also start logging in this file while I want to log error messages in different file. So, thus my error messages will be logged twicely in error file and in info file too. While I want that 'info' logger log just 'info' level messages not 'error' level messages too. And 'error' logger just log error messages.

Below is my Log4j Configuration:

```
log4j = {
def layoutPattern = new PatternLayout("[%d{ISO8601}] %m \r\n")
def dailyRollingInfoFile = new DailyRollingFileAppender(
        name:"rollingInfoFileAppender",
        layout: layoutPattern,
        //Path of the Log File
        fileName:"C:\\MS-Logs\\Application\\MSLogs.log",
        datePattern: "'.'dd-MM-yyyy")

def dailyRollingExceptionFile = new DailyRollingFileAppender(
        name:"rollingExceptionFileAppender",
        layout: layoutPattern,
        //Path of the Log File
        fileName:"C:\\MS-Logs\\Exceptions\\ExceptionLogs.log",
        datePattern: "'.'dd-MM-yyyy")

def dailyRollingExceptionAPIFile = new DailyRollingFileAppender(
        name:"rollingAPIFileAppender",
        layout: layoutPattern,
        //Path of the Log File
        fileName:"C:\\MS-Logs\\API\\MS-NotificationsLogs.log",
        datePattern: "'.'dd-MM-yyyy")

 //For logging exceptions stack trace
appenders {
    appender dailyRollingInfoFile
    appender dailyRollingExceptionFile
    appender dailyRollingExceptionAPIFile
   }

root {
    info  'rollingInfoFileAppender', additivity: false
    debug 'rollingAPIFileAppender', additivity: false
    error 'rollingExceptionFileAppender'
}
}
```

And Now, this is how I add filters:

```
dailyRollingExceptionFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter(levelToMatch:'ERROR', acceptOnMatch: true))
dailyRollingExceptionFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter())

//To make it sure that It will just Log, Messages by Info Logger
dailyRollingInfoFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter(levelToMatch:'INFO', acceptOnMatch: true))
dailyRollingInfoFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter())

//To make it sure that It will just Log, Messages by API Logger
dailyRollingAPIFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter(levelToMatch:'DEBUG', acceptOnMatch: true))
dailyRollingAPIFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter())
```

How, It may be possible to avoid same message being logged twicely in different files ? How can we log messages in different files without being repeating it in other file ?

Thanks for your Time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Log4j's `LevelMatchFilter` allows you to do what you're after:

```
def dailyRollingInfoFile = new DailyRollingFileAppender(...)
dailyRollingInfoFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter(levelToMatch:'INFO', acceptOnMatch: true))
dailyRollingInfoFile.addFilter(new org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter())
```

The `DenyAllFilter` drops the messages that the `LevelMatchFilter` does not match (ie. everything other than level INFO)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, Worked like a charm

Comment: Can you please make me understand that what additivity property does then ?

Comment: Additivity has to do with parent/child loggers, rather than log levels. The log4j manual offers detail: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity

Comment: Okay... Please see my edited question, there I have added how I add filter to filter my messages. But after that, When I log my messages, then just messages I log by 'logger.error()' are being logged properly while no mesg logs in their corresponding file when I use 'logger.debug()' or 'logger.info()'

Comment: I have tested this by both ways:
1. First I used the single logger:
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this);
to log all messages (info, debug, error)
2. Secondly, I have created separate loggers for logging each level of mesg:
    public static Logger infologger = Logger.getLogger("rollingInfoFileAppender");
    public static Logger debuglogger = Logger.getLogger("rollingAPIFileAppender");
    public static Logger exceptionlogger = Logger.getLogger("rollingExceptionFileAppender");

Comment: I don't quite follow your latest edits. If you can separate by package, you may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330436/grails-and-log4j-how-to-logs-in-different-files-with-same-level  Or, there are additional tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844945/grails-logging-multiple-loggers-and-appenders